# how to pass command line arguments in VS 2015 for debugging

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, command-line-arguments

i am using VS 2015 community. I would like to debug a code and hence want to pass it command line arguments. Here is the usage format and a snippet of the code where it reads the arguments.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    if(argc < 2) { //No file name provided!
        print_usage();
        return -1;
    }

    FILE *bin_out=NULL;
    int i;

    //Scan every option but last one(file name)
    for(i=1;i<argc-1;i++) {
        if(strcmp(argv[i], "-w") == 0) {
            rabin_sliding_window_size=get_uintval_from_arg(argc,i,argv,RAB_POLYNOMIAL_MIN_WIN_SIZE,RAB_POLYNOMIAL_MAX_WIN_SIZE);
            if(rabin_sliding_window_size > 0)
                i++;
            else
                return -1; //Illegal value, we are done!
        } else if(strcmp(argv[i],"-m") == 0) {
            rabin_polynomial_min_block_size=get_uintval_from_arg(argc-1,i,argv,1,UINT_MAX); 
            //May eventually actually add a limit here someday

            if(rabin_polynomial_min_block_size > 0) 
                i++;
            else 
                return -1;

        } else if(strcmp(argv[i],"-x") == 0) {
            rabin_polynomial_max_block_size=get_uintval_from_arg(argc-1,i,argv,1,UINT_MAX); 
            if(rabin_polynomial_max_block_size > 0) 
                i++;
            else 
                return -1;
        } else if(strcmp(argv[i],"-x") == 0) {
            rabin_polynomial_max_block_size=get_uintval_from_arg(argc-1,i,argv,1,UINT_MAX); 
            if(rabin_polynomial_max_block_size > 0)
                i++;
            else 
                return -1;
        } else if(strcmp(argv[i],"-a") == 0) {
            rabin_polynomial_average_block_size=get_uintval_from_arg(argc-1,i,argv,1,UINT_MAX);
            if(rabin_polynomial_average_block_size > 0)
                i++;
            else
                return -1;
        } else if(strcmp(argv[i], "-o") == 0) {
            if(i+1 < argc-1 ) {
                i++;
                bin_out=fopen(argv[i],"wb+");
                if(bin_out == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr,"Could not open file %s for writing, error code is %d!\n",argv[i],errno);
                }
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr,"Must specify file to output to.\n");
                print_usage();
                return -1;
            }
        }
```

I set the command arguments (in the project property page) to

> -o debgtst -w 32 -a 4098 -m 1024 -x 34762 input_file.pdf

but it gives many errors among which is

> sample.exe has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff)

if it helps:-
I have it run on Centos 7 with the following command line argument

```
sample -o debgtst -w 32 -a 4098 -m 1024 -x 34762 input_file
```

Comment: So set a breakpoint on your first `for` loop and step through the code in a debugger to see what's going wrong.

Comment: I did as you said and still could not figure out why. BTW, I have it run on Centos 7 and it executed right. Here is the input i used there "sample -o debgtst -w 32 -a 4098 -m 1024 -x 34762 input_file"

Comment: Your input does not help us, because we don't have the rest of the code. (And no, that's not a suggestion to add it to your post.) I highly doubt you stepped through the code as I suggested, because if you had you'd know **exactly** which line is causing the problem (and because it's been barely more than 30 minutes, which means that if you did you made very little effort to do so). Try again. *Step through the code in a debugger, starting with a break point on your first `for` statement.*

Comment: I traced that the first input is not valid somehow. it shows this when I watched the bin_out variable - "+  bin_out 0x00ee9b48 {_Placeholder=0x00000000 } _iobuf * ". And I have a question; do i need to use quotation to pass text arguments like "debgtst" or may be single quote?